# Display Firebase Notification Popup in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, uialertcontroller

**Notice: Solution at the bottom.**

**Original issue.**
I followed the directions on firebase to set up push notifications in iOS. I do successfully get notification to the phone and will display at the top of the phone if the app is closed, but if I'm in the app the notification never displays. I see the print out in the terminal though so I know its receiving the notification.

Ideal functionality would be:
1) if app is closed or in background when the user clicks the notification it opens the app then a in app popup alert will display with the notification with a Okay button to click

2) if the app is in the foreground the notification displays as a popup alert with a Okay button to click.

Below is the AppDelegate.swift code which when I run it and send a notification, I get the notification but I also get the following error when trying to display the alert. ***Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController on Company.AuthorizationCheckViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!***

Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import Sentry

import UserNotifications

import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate  {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        VersionCheck.shared.IsUpdateRequired()
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        let message : [String : Any] = userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
        let messageAlert : [String : Any] = message["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let lBody : String = messageAlert["body"] as! String
        let lTitle : String = messageAlert["title"] as! String

        print("body 1 = \(lBody)") //this works!
        print("title = \(lTitle)") //this works!

        let alert = UIAlertController(title:  lTitle, message: lBody, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil);
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        let message : [String : Any] = userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
        let messageAlert : [String : Any] = message["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let lBody : String = messageAlert["body"] as! String
        let lTitle : String = messageAlert["title"] as! String

        print("body 2 = \(lBody)")
        print("title = \(lTitle)")

      let alert = UIAlertController(title:  lTitle, message: lBody, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil);
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
    }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        let message : [String : Any] = userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
        let messageAlert : [String : Any] = message["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let lBody : String = messageAlert["body"] as! String
        let lTitle : String = messageAlert["title"] as! String

        print("body 3 = \(lBody)")
        print("title = \(lTitle)")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title:  lTitle, message: lBody, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        completionHandler([UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)") //can use the id later to privent multiple popups of the same message
        }

        let message : [String : Any] = userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
        let messageAlert : [String : Any] = message["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let lBody : String = messageAlert["body"] as! String
        let lTitle : String = messageAlert["title"] as! String

        print("body 4 = \(lBody)")
        print("title = \(lTitle)")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title:  lTitle, message: lBody, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
}
```

***Solution:***

I added PresentedViewController? to the code and it allowed the alert popup to display. 
Also by adding UIBackgroundFetchResults.newData to the completionHandler I was able to have the notification displayed in the app

new code looks like this

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title:  lTitle, message: lBody, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
```